# how to get a specific material from a meshrenderer using raycasts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Meshrenderer with 9 materials on it and I want to detect which one of those colors is facing forward, but I don't know which one it is going to be so I can't just use `Meshrenderer.materials[number].color`

here is what I have so far

```
    public GameObject Shot1pos;

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(Shot1pos.transform.position, Shot1pos.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            {
                Debug.DrawRay(Shot1pos.transform.position, Shot1pos.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.yellow);
                Wheel1Color = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;
                Debug.Log(Wheel1Color);
            }
```

but this only returns the first material, whichever is facing forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. First of all you need to get the mesh index according to `hit.triangleIndex` and get the main material index based on it.

For first one just copy this script in class:

```
public static int GetSubMeshIndex(Mesh mesh, int triangleIndex)
{
    if (!mesh.isReadable) return 0;
    
    var triangleCounter = 0;
    for (var subMeshIndex = 0; subMeshIndex < mesh.subMeshCount; subMeshIndex++)
    {
        var indexCount = mesh.GetSubMesh(subMeshIndex).indexCount;
        triangleCounter += indexCount / 3;
        if (triangleIndex < triangleCounter) return subMeshIndex;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Then use this part for detecting Suitable material:

```
public void DetectMaterial(RaycastHit hit)
{
    if (hit.transform == null) return;

    var materials = hit.transform.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials;

    var index = hit.triangleIndex;

    var mesh = hit.transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    
    var subMeshIndex = GetSubMeshIndex(mesh, index);
    
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(materials[subMeshIndex]);
}
```

Remember that your file model must have `Read / Write Enabled` option enabled and use only `Mesh Collider`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have been trying to get this for the past few days